# Mockito Android with AndroidJUnitRunner error

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to use Mockito Android with AndroidJUnitRunner and getting error. I tried many other combinations of gradle dependencies but no luck. Where am I wrong?

```
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

Here is gradle test compile block

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.12.0'

androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:runner:+', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
})
```

And I am getting error

> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Mockito cannot mock
>   this class: interface
>   *.CourseWebService.
>
> Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes. If you're not
>   sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.
>
> IMPORTANT INFORMATION FOR ANDROID USERS:
>
> The regular Byte Buddy mock makers cannot generate code on an Android
>   VM! To resolve this, please use the 'mockito-android' dependency for
>   your application:
>   http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22mockito-android%22%20g%3A%22org.mockito%22
>
> Java               : 0.9 JVM vendor name    : The Android Project JVM
>   vendor version : 2.1.0 JVM name           : Dalvik JVM version
>   : 0.9 JVM info           : null OS name            : Linux OS version 
>   : 3.18.31-perf-gcd8e090
>
> Underlying exception : `com.android.dex.util.ExceptionWithContext:
>   com.android.dx.cf.attrib.RawAttribute cannot be cast to
>   com.android.dx.cf.attrib.AttSignature`

Here is Test class:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class CourseTest {

    @Mock
    CourseWebService courseWebService;


    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        gson = new NetworkingConfigurationModule().provideGson();
        assertNotNull(gson);
    }
}
```

Comment: is the CourseWebService class private or final ?

Comment: @andrei no of course, just a public interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)` with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class`.
Also, in your `setup()` method, you can add this line : `courseWebService = mock(CourseWebService.class)`.

Comment: If change to `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`, it says `Empty test suite`

Comment: Try to change `androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.12.0'`to `androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.11.0'`.

Comment: This definitely isn't working for me either. I'm also getting `Empty test suite.`

Comment: To solve the empty test suite error, clean and make project again. If it still doesn't work, close it and re-import it.